# Store files ordered by last modified date in Azure File Share

Tags: azure, mailhog

I keep Mailhog e-mails in Azure File Storage. The storage keeps them ordered by name, I need them to be ordered by last modified time, the default ordering causes them to be unordered when retrieved by Mailhog. Is that possible to store them in last modified date order?

Comment: How are you writing files to Azure Storage?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Mailhog is, I just have specified the volume that it uses and I see that what it does it retrieves them from Azure in sequence that they're stored and they stored ordered by name, so to have it working as expected I need them ordered by date in Azure already.

Comment: Azure File Storage will save the file as it is written by the client (Mailhog) in this case. It won't do any renaming on its own. This is something you would need to do.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS As I wrote, I would like to store them by date, not name.

Comment: I get that. So unless you're writing code to save the file, you can't tell Azure File Service to save a file with a particular name. I'm assuming that you have mapped a File Service Share as a network drive and Mailhog is writing directly to that drive. One solution would be to tell Mailhog to save the files in the format you would like (i.e. store them by date) or write some code to rename the file after the file is written.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Got that part: `err = ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(maildir.Path, string(m.ID)), b, 0660)` this is what they do line 46 https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/blob/master/vendor/github.com/mailhog/storage/maildir.go  as this project seems to be dead for 1.5 years I wanted to fix that on Azure end, to tell it somehow to serve files ordered by date not name.